# Update statement for a list of strings

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I'm using `sqlite3` and my table has a text field that actually has a list of strings.

So a sample select (`select * from table where id=1`) would return for example

```
1|foo@bar.com|21-03-2015|["foo", "bar", "foobar"]
```

I couldn't figure out how the sqlite statement for updating the list is though. I tried

```
update table set list="["foo", "bar"] where id=1;
update table set list=["foo", "bar"] where id=1;
update table set list="\["foo", "bar"\]" where id=1;
update table set list=(value) where id=1 VALUES (["foo", "bar"])
```

Comment: What programming language are you actually using?

Comment: @CL. I use Python for the websie itself, but now I just want to directly edit it using the `sqlite3` CLI interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the statement you need:

```
UPDATE table SET list = '[\"foo\", \"bar\"]' WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Actually you don't even need to escape `"` anymore.